# Cannot read .xlsx file in R

Tags: r, excel, csv, xlsx, data-import

How do I read excel files with `.xlsx` extension in [r](/questions/tagged/r) programming language? I have tried installing package [xlsx](/questions/tagged/xlsx) but after I run `library(xlsx)` I get -

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
>    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘xlsx’ was built under R version 3.5.3 ".

Further, how can I convert `.xlsx` file to `.csv` file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R write dataframe to excel without admin rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188571/r-write-dataframe-to-excel-without-admin-rights)

Comment: The answers given about `readxl` are good. The `xlsx` package also provides capability to _write_ Excel files, which involves much more than you require. It also depends on `rJava` and having Java's JDK installed on your system. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/readme/README.html, under "Common Problems".

Answer (score 5):

try `readxl` package:

```
library(readxl)
read_excel("your_file.xlsx", sheet = yourSheet_number)
```

You can convert .xlsx to .csv by reading .xlsx and then saving with `readr` package:

```
library(readr)
write_csv(yourFile, "yourDirectory")
```

Comment: Thank you so much I will try it out.

Answer (score 4):

This code should help:

```
library(readxl)
dataset <- read_xlsx("myfile.xlsx")
write.csv(dataset,"mycsv.csv")
```

Comment: Be sure to check out the help file on `write.csv`, particularly how `NA` are handled.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.